# mysql query - error showing mysql results using inner join

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, inner-join

I have 2 tables that I want to merge. I want to print all the products with their corresponding total quantity and total amount.

This is what I have.

```
//Product Table 
productID    productName
   1              A
   2              B
   3              C


//Order Record (This came from 2 tables that I have successfully merged)
orderID     productID     quantity     amount
   1            1             5         100
   2            2             2         50
   3            2             3         150
```

I want to do this

```
productID     productName     totalQuantity     totalAmount
    1             A                 8               250
    2             B                 2                50
    3             C                 0                0      
//instead of 0 for total Quantity and total Amount, it shows 2 and 50 respectively.
```

Here is my php code. It correctly outputs the the data for the first 2 rows (product A and B) but when it comes to the last row (product C), it copies the data for product B. Please tell me what's wrong in my code? Thank you in advance.

```
$products = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_products");

foreach($products as $product){
   $productID = $product->productID; 
   $productName = $product->productName;

   $orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT a.productID, SUM(a.quantity) as totalQuantity, SUM(a.amount) as totalSales FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.orderID = b.orderID GROUP BY productID");

   if(is_null($orders)){
      $totalQuantity = 0;
      $totalSales = '0.00';
   }

   foreach($orders as $order){
      $totalQuantity = $order->totalQuantity; 
      $totalSales = $order->totalSales; 
   }

   $orderItem = array(
                        'productID' => $productID,
                        'productName' => $productName,
                        'totalQuantity' => $totalQuantity,
                        'totalSales' => $totalSales
                     );
               $records[] = $orderItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is (just add `WHERE` to your query):

```
$orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
        a.productID, 
        SUM(a.quantity) as totalQuantity, 
        SUM(a.amount) as totalSales 
        FROM a 
        INNER JOIN b 
        ON a.orderID = b.orderID 
        WHERE a.productID = $productID
        GROUP BY productID");
```

But looking at your fragment, I believe you can simplify it (**replace full fragment**) to:

```
$records = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
       p.productID, 
       p.productName, 
       COALESCE(SUM(a.quantity),0) as totalQuantity, 
       COALESCE(SUM(a.amount),0) as totalSales
     FROM wp_products p
     LEFT JOIN a 
     GROUP BY p.productID");
```

Comment: I did a foreach loop on the products, then for every product i queried its total quantity and sales. I used this code `$orders = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT table_a.productID, SUM(table_a.quantity) as totalQuantity, SUM(able_a.amount) as totalSales FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.orderID = table_b.orderID GROUP BY productID");` I am getting the correct values except for those who are suppose to get 0 for totalQuantity and totalSales.

Comment: Coalesce is not working. I also tried IFNULL and it's not working as well.

Comment: what do you mean by *not working* ? and there is neither `able_a.amount` nor `table_a.quantity` nor `table_a` at all in my code. So try to be more precise and provide exact table names and table's schema

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your query is correct.

I don't see the table names.  Try changing it to:

```
FROM `tablename` AS a INNER JOIN `othertable` AS b
```

Swap out tablename and other table with the names for table a and b.